# count a column based on case condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's the code:

```
select  sum(case when status_code= '200' then 1 else 0 end) as success,
      sum(case when status_code!= '200' then 1 else 0 end ) as failure from my_table
```

Output:

```
success  failure    
  1          2
```

I'll have to select count failure only when failure count is < = 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

Add a [having](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql) clause.

```
select sum(case when status_code= '200' then 1 else 0 end) as 'success',
       sum(case when status_code!= '200' then 1 else 0 end) as 'failure'
from my_table
having sum(case when status_code!= '200' then 1 else 0 end) <= 5;
```

---

**Full example**

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dcd43fc3fbfb54994bdbb701f9852e5d)

With results:

```
declare @my_table table
(
    status_code int
);

insert into @my_table (status_code) values
(200), (1), (1); --> 2 failures

select  sum(case when status_code  = 200 then 1 else 0 end) as 'success',
        sum(case when status_code != 200 then 1 else 0 end) as 'failure'
from @my_table
having  sum(case when status_code != 200 then 1 else 0 end) <= 5;


-- RESULT (1 row)
success     failure
----------- -----------
1           2
```

Without results:

```
insert into @my_table (status_code) values
(1), (1), (1), (1); --> +4 failures ==> 6 failures in total

select  sum(case when status_code  = 200 then 1 else 0 end) as 'success',
        sum(case when status_code != 200 then 1 else 0 end) as 'failure'
from @my_table
having  sum(case when status_code != 200 then 1 else 0 end) <= 5;


-- RESULT (0 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code.

```sql
Select * from (select  sum(case when status_code= '200' then 1 else 0 end) as success,
      sum(case when status_code!= '200' then 1 else 0 end ) as failure from my_table ) t
where t.failure <= 5
```

Comment: Always format your code using {} brackets and add some description

Answer (score 1):

You can just use subquery:

```
Select * from 
(
select  sum(case when status_code= '200' then 1 else 0 end) as success,
      sum(case when status_code!= '200' then 1 else 0 end ) as failure from my_table 
) A
Where failure<=5
```